# referencing in subfloat not working

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

```
\documentclass[journal]{./IEEE/IEEEtran}
  \usepackage{cite,graphicx}
  \usepackage{url}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[H]
   \subfloat[Piknik]{\includegraphics[scale=.035,angle=-90]  {images/piknik2.jpg}}      {\label{piknik}}\qquad 
  \subfloat[Oishi]{\includegraphics[scale=.035,angle=-90] {images/oishi2.jpg}}\qquad
  \subfloat[Gardenia]{\includegraphics[scale=.035,angle=-90]{images/gardenia2.jpg}}\qquad
  \end{figure}

  one of the... \ref{piknik} ....
 \end{document}
```

I want to reference an image from the figure to a paragraph using \ref but it is not working. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

When you process your example document you'll receive several warnings; the second one is something like the following:

```
Package caption Warning: `\label` without proper `\caption` on input line 10.
See the `caption` package documentation for explanation.
```

which suggests that you had the `\label` for the subfigure in the wrong position (in fact, it was outside `\subfloat`).

The safest place to use `\label` with `\subfloat` is either right after the caption inside the first optional argument (as in my example below) or inside the mandatory argument:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \subfloat[Piknik\label{piknik}]{\includegraphics[scale=.035,angle=-90]{images/piknik2.jpg}}\qquad 
  \subfloat[Oishi]{\includegraphics[scale=.035,angle=-90] {images/oishi2.jpg}}\qquad
  \subfloat[Gardenia]{\includegraphics[scale=.035,angle=-90]{images/gardenia2.jpg}}
\end{figure}

A cross-reference to subfigure~\ref{piknik} ....

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that using the `caption` package with the `IEEEtran` document class might produce undesired results; you should load the `subfig` package with the `caption=false` option, as I did in my example code.

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Of course, restore the original first line to load the class.

Comment: `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` is the proper way with `IEEEtran`.