# How to insert subfigure with caption in IEEE trans?

Tags: graphics, ieeetran

I am trying to insert some subfigures with caption to all the figure in IEEE trans and i don't want to span two columns. But it is not working. I want to do the following:
[image] .
And what i tried:

```
\begin{figure}[ht] 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{images/1a}
    \caption{} 
    \label{1a} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure}%%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{images/1b}
    \caption{} 
    \label{1b} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure}%%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{images/1c} 
    \caption{} 
    \label{1c} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure}%%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{images/1d} 
    \caption{} 
    \label{1d}
    \vspace{4ex} 
    \end{subfigure}
  \caption{(a),(b)Some examples from CIFAR-10 \cite{4}. The objects in single-label
images are usually roughly aligned.(c),(d) However, the assumption of object alignment is not valid for multi-label
images. Also note the partial visibility and occlusion
between objects in the multi-label images.}
  \label{fig1} 
\end{figure}
```

How can i achieve it??

Comment: I cannot run your MWE as I don't have your images, but I imagine the overall width of the figure, having 4 figures in it, each half a linewidth, would be about 2 lines wide. Did you try `\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{images/1a}` ? Also, it would be wise for the overall width to be a little less than 1 lines wide, as there will be spaces between figures... maybe `0.2 \linewidth` or less ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you read `IEEEtran` documentation will see that it recommends not using `subfigure` package but `subfig`. And an example with `subfig` is explained in it.

What I understand you want is something like this:

[image]

which can be obtained with following code:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
    \usepackage[caption=false, font=normalsize, labelfont=sf, textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage[caption=false, font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\lipsum

\section{B}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{figure} 
    \centering
  \subfloat[a\label{1a}]{%
       \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
  \subfloat[b\label{1b}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \\
  \subfloat[c\label{1c}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
  \subfloat[d\label{1d}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
  \caption{(a), (b) Some examples from CIFAR-10 \cite{4}. The objects in     
        single-label images are usually roughly aligned.(c),(d) However, the 
        assumption of object alignment is not valid for multi-label
        images. Also note the partial visibility and occlusion
        between objects in the multi-label images.}
  \label{fig1} 
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you update your answer, due to issues in referencing the subfloats which is addressed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169477/22492)?

Answer (score 4):

here is another way:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[First caption]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=1.0in]{imagefile2}
        \label{fig:first_sub}
    }
    \\
    \subfigure[Second caption]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=1.0in]{imagefile2}
        \label{fig:second_sub}
    }
    \subfigure[Third caption]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=1.0in]{imagefile2}
        \label{fig:third_sub}
    }
    \caption{Common figure caption.}
    \label{fig:sample_subfigures}
\end{figure}
```

And the output:

[image]