# Error including four figures in a column with IEEETran class

Tags: floats, subfloats, ieeetran

I am trying to include 4 figures arranged 2figs x 2figs in a column like this

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage[compress]{cite}
\usepackage{times} % Font Times New Roman throughout the document
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\newcommand{\prob}[1]{p(#1)}
%\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}
\newcommand*\overbar[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\hull}[1]{\mbox{$<$$#1$$>$}}
\newcommand{\stext}[1]{{\scriptscriptstyle \text{#1}}}
\let\oldemptyset\emptyset
\let\emptyset\varnothing


\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
% \usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
    ñlakdfñlakdjfñlakdjfñlkjls
    ´ñsdfádjñlakdjñlakdjñlakdjñalkdjf

    \begin{figure}[t!]
            \centering
         \begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/Q4_c.eps}
                \caption{{Q=4, \#tags=100}}
                \label{fig:subfigure1}
            \end{subfigure}
            \hfill
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/Q4Poiss_c.eps}
                \caption{{Q=4, $\lambda=100$}}
                \label{fig:subfigure2}
            \end{subfigure}
            \vskip\baselineskip
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/DFSA_c.eps}
                \caption{{DFSA, \#tags{=}100}}
                \label{fig:subfigure3}
            \end{subfigure}
            \hfill
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/DFSAPoiss_c.eps}
                \caption{{DFSA, $\lambda{=1}00$}}
                \label{fig:subfigure4}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{Probability of block identification.}
            \label{fig:contour4}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

    ñlakdñlkajdfñlkajdñflkjañldskjf
    asdklfñlakdjlakjdñlakdjf
    ñlkasdjfñlakdjfñakdjñlaksdjf
\end{document}
```

but it gives error compiling `Latex Error: ./test.tex:76 Missing number, treated as zero.`.

If I remove the `{0.48\linewidth}`the compilation goes fine, but the figures are placed one below the other.

I would like to get this result

[image]

What am I missing? How could I fix this?

Regards

**EDIT**

I have also tried:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage[compress]{cite}
\usepackage{times} % Font Times New Roman throughout the document
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\newcommand{\prob}[1]{p(#1)}
%\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}
\newcommand*\overbar[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\hull}[1]{\mbox{$<$$#1$$>$}}
\newcommand{\stext}[1]{{\scriptscriptstyle \text{#1}}}
\let\oldemptyset\emptyset
\let\emptyset\varnothing


\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
% \usepackage{subcaption}


    \begin{document}
        ñlakdfñlakdjfñlakdjfñlkjls
        ´ñsdfádjñlakdjñlakdjñlakdjñalkdjf



        \begin{figure}
            \centering
          \subfloat[a\label{1a}]{%
               \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figs/Q4_c.eps}}
            \hfill
          \subfloat[b\label{1b}]{%
                \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figs/Q4Poiss_c.eps}}
            \\
          \subfloat[c\label{1c}]{%
                \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figs/DFSA_c.eps}}
            \hfill
          \subfloat[d\label{1d}]{%
                \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figs/DFSAPoiss_c.eps}}
          \caption{(a), (b) Some examples from CIFAR-10 \cite{4}. Tmages.}
          \label{fig1}
        \end{figure}

        ñlakdñlkajdfñlkajdñflkjañldskjf
        asdklfñlakdjlakjdñlakdjf
        ñlkasdjfñlakdjfñakdjñlaksdjf
    \end{document}
```

with latex gives

[image]

and with pdflatex

it does not show any document and gives errors:

[image]

Comment: unrelated but don't load the epsfig package unless you need to emulate documents from the 1980s using the psfig syntax.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the comment. I would not load `epsfig`. Thanks.

Comment: @user1993416: The `subfigure` package is deprecated. You could either use `subfig` or the `subcaption` package instead.

Comment: Maybe help : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305492/31034

Comment: @ferahfeza I have tried the solution of the link and still does not compile. I am trying LaTeX and pdfLaTeX compilation. I have also tested the `subfig` and `subcaption` packages commented above, but still not compiling well.

Comment: @user1993416: Could you please edit your question to include what you have tried with the `subfloat` package? Including the error message could also be helpful.

Comment: @leandris I have edited the document.

Comment: Did you compile with `\usepackage{epsfig}` or without `\usepackage{epsfig}` in your code? Without it seems to compile with `example-image-a.eps`, but of course there could still be a problem with your used images ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code works for me using `subfig` package instead of `subfigure`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage[compress]{cite}
\usepackage{times} % Font Times New Roman throughout the document
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
%\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\newcommand{\prob}[1]{p(#1)}
%\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}
\newcommand*\overbar[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\hull}[1]{\mbox{$<$$#1$$>$}}
\newcommand{\stext}[1]{{\scriptscriptstyle \text{#1}}}
\let\oldemptyset\emptyset
\let\emptyset\varnothing


\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
% \usepackage{subcaption}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
    \usepackage[caption=false, font=normalsize, labelfont=sf, textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage[caption=false, font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi


\begin{document}
    ñlakdfñlakdjfñlakdjfñlkjls
    ´ñsdfádjñlakdjñlakdjñlakdjñalkdjf

   \begin{figure} 
    \centering
  \subfloat[Q=4, \#tags=100\label{1a}]{%
       \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
  \subfloat[Q=4, $\lambda=100$\label{1b}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \\
  \subfloat[DFSA, \#tags{=}100\label{1c}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
  \subfloat[DFSA, $\lambda{=1}00$\label{1d}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
  \caption{Probability of block identification.}
  \label{fig1} 
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-5]

    ñlakdñlkajdfñlkajdñflkjañldskjf
    asdklfñlakdjlakjdñlakdjf
    ñlkasdjfñlakdjfñakdjñlaksdjf
\end{document}
```

[image]