# Subfigures With Captions for IEEE Conf

Tags: subcaption, subfig, ieeeconf

I am creating a latex project with the document class [ieeeconf](http://ras.papercept.net/conferences/support/files/ieeeconf.zip):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
```

I need to include some a figure with some subfigures, similar to what is shown in [this article on positioning images](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_images_and_tables#Multiple_images_in_one_figure) (i.e. a figure with multiple subfigure images that each get there own caption numbering a,b,etc.) and another caption for the entire image: 
[image: image with 2 subfigures that have subcaptions and a caption for the whole image]

However, since I ham using the ieeeconf documentclass, I get warning errors if I try to use either the subcaption package (as recommended in the link above) or the subfig package (as I saw recommended elsewhere).

What is the correct package to use here?

Comment: Probably interesing: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305492/134144

Comment: You could give `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` a try. (`caption=false` is the important part.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @leandriis I tried using the code there (the part with \ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc but still got a bunch of errors, including:
"\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AxelSommerfeldt Unfortunately, when I tried that, I got a 2 warning messages. 1. that my document class has a bad definition of \endfigure, 2. my document class has a bad definition of \endtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the images inside a `tabular`

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEconf}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ c @{\hspace{20pt}} c }
    \includegraphics[width=.3\columnwidth]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[width=.3\columnwidth]{example-image-b} \\
    \small (a) &
      \small (b)
  \end{tabular}

  \medskip

  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The space between the images is set using `\hspace{20pt}` in the `tabular` column specification. Also, the subfigure numbering is set using `\small`, with a skip between the images and the main figure caption using `\medskip` (a vertical skip of size `\medskipamount`).